# Change text color of selected item of Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, textcolor

I am creating an application in which I have one `Listview`. When I select item of this `Listview`, one `Alert dialog` appears. 
In this Alert dialog, there is also one `Listview`. Items in this Listview are depends on the user inputs.
 Now, when I select item in this listview, text color must be changed and when I again select this item, text color must change to its original color. 
What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Add a map to your class that tracks your selected items:

```
HashMap <Integer, Boolean> selectionStates = new HashMap <String, Boolean>();
```

Use a custom adapter for your ListView. In getView, set the color according to the value in your map:

```
if (selectionStates.contains(position) && selectionStates.get(position){
  yourTextView.setTextColor(selectedColor);
}
else {
  yourTextView.setTextColor(normalColor);
}
```

Add an onItemClickListener to your ListView e.g. in onCreate:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    boolean alreadySelected = false;
    if (selectionStates.contains(position) && selectionStates.get(position) alreadySelected = true;
    selectionStates.put(position, !alreadySelected);

    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourItemTextView);

    if (selectionStates.contains(position) && selectionStates.get(position){
      yourTextView.setTextColor(selectedColor);
    }
    else {
      yourTextView.setTextColor(normalColor);
    }
  }
};
```

This will not only change the color of an item immediately after it has been selected, but also retain the color after scrolling.

As an adapter, you could extend ArrayAdapter:

```
yourListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<WhatEverClass>(ArgumentsHere){
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      TextView yourTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourItemTextView);

      if (selectionStates.contains(position) && selectionStates.get(position){
         yourTextView.setTextColor(selectedColor);
      }
      else {
         yourTextView.setTextColor(normalColor);
      }
  }
});
```

Please note that I did not test this code, but it should at least give you an idea of what your code should look like.

Comment: Hey I have implemented as you saiid. But not getting yet. Can you check my code here? And tell me what needs to be replaced?

Comment: final HashMap<Integer, Boolean> selectionStates = new HashMap <Integer, Boolean>();
lvDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
     
     boolean alreadySelected = false;
        
    TextView tvChange = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);
     
    if (selectionStates.containsValue(arg2) && selectionStates.get(arg2) )
    {
     tvChange.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    
    else 
    {
         tvChange.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    
   }
  });

Comment: What ListView adapter are you using?

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter